# How to debug on device with MonoDevelop and MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am part of the Apple iOS Dev Program and I have the paid version of MonoTouch. Now how do I debug on my iPhone?  AppIDs, provisioning, KeyChain???  I am lost. I have built simple apps in the simulator but cannot figure out how to debug on my device. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to the provisioning portal (https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)and create a development certificate which you install in your keychain and a provisioning profile associated with your development certificate. You also have to add your device as a development device, also done through the portal. The steps to do all this are given on the provisioning portal site. After you have that all set up, look at the MonoTouch documentation on how to choose the correct profile to build your application against so it will install on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the debugging docs for MonoTouch?

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Debugging

Comment: That only covers the Mono side of things. Apparently there is a bunch of stuff that needs to happen on the Apple side first. Provisioning and setting up App IDs?